# Notice: Undefined variable: num

Tags: php, mysqli

I have three files `conn.php`, `func.php` and `index.php` in the `conn.php` i have my connection to the database and in `index.php` I've included the connection file while in `func.php` I've a function that counts the number of columns

`func.php`

```
<?php
function countusers($connection, $column, $table)
{
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "
                                    SELECT
                                        COUNT($column)
                                    FROM
                                        $table");
    if($stmt)
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $num);
        mysqli_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    return $num;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work I've tried adding the connection file in the function and it worked.

here is my index file

index.php

```
<?php
require_once "conn.php";
include "func.php";
echo countusers($conn, "id", "mods");
```

conn.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test", 3306);
if(!$conn)
{
    echo "An Error Occurred";
}
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: Maybe you had better show us the `conn.php` as that look like it should work to me unless there is an issue with the connection

Comment: Nope just a notice `Notice: Undefined variable: num`

Comment: See [correct code for connection in Example 1 of the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: @Hallur No _I missed that too_ That is binding a variable for the result of the query

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I see, you're correct... so then $num is just never defined inside the function. maybe OP forgot to include it in the function. Anyway, moving on to next question

Comment: I wonder if this off topic question will ever get enough votes to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick read up in php.net states that the bind_result must occur after the execute... I have not run this so its a suggestion only.

So you could try...

```
//... SNIP...
    if($stmt)
    {
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // Changed this to  mysqli_stmt_execute       
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $num);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    else {
       $num = 0;
    }
    return $num;
// ... SNIP ...
```

Also what is your default value for $num in the case that $stmt is false? You need to decide and set that.

UPDATE: The default value for $num has been added in the case the stmt fails for any reason. I have since run this code and it works.

The changes suggested in the code snippet DOES provide a value for $num, whereas the original code did not.

As to the validity of the actual method/implementation used is another matter, this answer directly addressed the question at hand.

Comment: Grand, but do take note of the error reporting code suggestions that you can add that was provided by @RiggsFolly and others, as this is an important tool everyone needs in debugging these things.

Comment: This answer is wrong and it cannot be deleted because it's accepted. I wish I had the ability to remove such rubbish despite what silly OP thinks

Comment: @YourCommonSense, Hey if it's wrong feel free to provide the correct answer or we can fix this one. As stated it was a suggestion based upon some quick reading up on the subject and the OP states it worked for them so, please feel free to enlighten us cause I am curious.

Comment: **This blessed site is not to enlighten curious**. Nor for a pleasant chatter. It is for providing answers to questions. And you better know the answer if happen to write one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I've run the code and it works. If it's an issue regarding the implementation, remember it was to solve the initial question regarding the undefined var $num which it does! Not a How to do it the "proper" way which is what I am gathering you are taking issue with and I'll wear that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once "conn.php";
require_once "func.php";

echo countusers($conn, "id", "mods");
```

Comment: If `mysqli_` is involved this is a better error reporting set `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`